# how do i fix "import dns ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'dns'" on my macbook using vscode, i am new to programming

Tags: python, module, dns

import dns.resolver

ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'dns'  my code wont run, until i fix this and dns python is already installed in the environment i use

I have tried uninstalling an.pd installing, and changing the environment also but doesn't work, I use python 3.9.13 on vs code

Answer (score 0):

You have to run your python file in the same folder as the dns file.

For example here is your file structure:

```
|
|--- dns.py
|--- main.py

# main.py file and dns file in the same folder.
```

in the main.py file:

```
import dns
# It will work
```

For example here is your file structure:

```
|
|--- dns.py
|--- folder
      |--- main.py
# main.py file and dns file are not in the same folder.
```

in the main.py file:

```
import dns
# It will error
```

Comment: How do i go about this?